# Problem with first order diferential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need some help to understand how to solve by power series $xy'-2y=0$ my problem is when I try to find the recursion formul of the coefficients I can't put my effort cuz I'm on cellphone and it's difficult please I need understand this.

A picture that what I've done:[image]

Comment: Sorry tha image ar inverted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will copy the last two lines of your work here because the image is inverted and difficult to read.

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^n-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n=0\\-2a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(na_n-2a_n)x^n=0$$

From here, the constant term is $-2a_0$ on the LHS and $0$ on the RHS, so we can conclued that $$-2a_0=0\implies a_0=0$$

Next, $$na_n-2a_n=0\implies(n-2)a_n=0$$
So if $n\neq2$, then $a_n=0$. So the only non-zero coefficient is for $n=2$.

So the solution is $$y=a_2x^2$$

---

I'd also like to point out this is separable and much easier to solve in this way

$$xy'-2y=0\implies\frac{y'}y=\frac2x\implies\log y=\log(x^2)+c\implies y=Cx^2$$ where $C=e^c$.